# Utf-8 in subdomain?

Tags: utf-8, dns, subdomain, idn

Is it possible to use UTF-8 in a subdomain? If so, which characters are allowed and how does the can't-mix-encodings thing work?

I've tried to RTFM, but Google wan't of much [help](http://www.google.com.ua/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=utf8+in+subdomains#hl=en&pq=utf%208%20in%20subdomains&xhr=t&q=utf+8+in+subdomain&cp=18&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=utf+8+in+subdomain&pbx=1&fp=8ecf81493e3605ca&bs=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't many things special about subdomains. A given domain name `foo.example.com` is an ordered list of labels (`foo`, `example`, `com`). So you might want to know if you can use UTF-8 in a given label.

The low level answer is that a label is defined as:

```
<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
<letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in upper case and a through z in lower case
<digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9
<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"
```

which means that you can only find `[-a-zA-Z0-9]` in a label.

However, [IDNA](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3490.txt) can be used to encode Unicode characters. In short, a label containing other characters is encoded with: `"xn--" + punycode(nameprep(label))`.

As for limitations at least:

- for characters can't be in a IDN label (U+002E, U+3002, U+FF0E, U+FF61).

Comment: Link-only answers are bad in general (and I also happen not to be able to find much relating to the actual question of *subdomains* there)